Inflation and Purchasing Power Variation Inconsistency
I am stuck on a really simple problem and it's making me lose my mind:
Suppose you have 2000 dollars in your bank account, and suppose the inflation is at 2 percent. The future value of your money, after let's say 3 years, will then be, by definition:
$$2000 \cdot (1+0.02)^3 \approx 2122$$
This implies that in 3 years you have lost approximately
$$2122 - 2000 = 122 \tag{1}$$
by keeping your money stuck and not investing.
But there is another approach to calculate things: having 2 percent inflation rate should mean that you retain 98 percent of your purchasing power (right?), so after 3 years the real purchasing power in your bank account is:
$$2000 \cdot (0.98)^3 \approx 1882$$
This means a lost equal to:
$$ 2000 - 1882 = 118 \tag{2} $$
I don't get why (1) and (2) are not the same! They should measure the same thing! It should be the purchasing power lost in dollars with respect to the value of the dollars right now! Why do I get different results?

Edit: Since the problem probably lies in a different unit of measurement for the outcomes (future dollars vs. present dollars) I would like an answer that attaches units of measurement to the variables at play, inflation rates included, to properly show how the two process lead to different results

The first calculation gives you a loss of purchasing power measured in future dollars. The second way measures the loss in present dollars.
Future dollars have a lower present value than present dollars, so it takes more of them to make the same present value.
Your first calculation is in future dollars because it’s the “future value of my money.” You compared having $\$2122$ three years in the future and having $\$2000$ three years in the future.

By the way, there is no place in this exercise where you should multiply by $0.98^3$.
Instead, to calculate the purchasing power of $\$2000$ in three years, you should divide by $1.02^3$.
The result is $\$1884.64$, so your purchasing power is $\$115.36$ less in present dollars.
That’s an even greater discrepancy than you calculated. But it needs to be that big, because one present dollar is worth $1.02^3$ future dollars.
More generally, it’s best to look for ratios rather than differences in these problems. The opposite of a $25\%$ increase is not a $25\%$ decrease; it’s a $20\%$ decrease, because $1/1.25=0.8$.

Ok, but my problem is that I don't get why the first method measures the loss in terms of future dollars.. Can you expand on why?
